# PHP | PDO - SELECT QUERY COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to carry out a simple count of a query, however it just simply wont work. What am I doing wrong?

```
$STH_SELECT = $pdo->query("SELECT count(*) FROM data WHERE Location = $locationDayout");
$count = $STH_SELECT->fetchColumn();
```

> $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username,
>   $password);

Comment: `$count = $STH_SELECT->rowCount();`